# How to alignment datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

ı have a problem. I want a alignment problem in my datatables. This is my table : https://prnt.sc/nk9moz 
[image]
if ı added excel export hide a entries bar. Look : http://prntscr.com/nk9n7r

[image]
how can ı alignment this table and show this bar with export ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#datatables').DataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "lengthMenu": [
                    [10, 25, 50, -1],
                    [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                ],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        text: 'Excele Aktar',
                        className: 'btn btn-default',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                responsive: true,
                language: {
                    search: "_INPUT_",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Kayıt ara",
                    zeroRecords: "Kayıt bulunamadı",
                },


            });


            var table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

            // Edit record
            table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
                $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

                var data = table.row($tr).data();
                alert('You press on Row: ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] + '\'s row.');
            });

            // Delete a record
            table.on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
                $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                table.row($tr).remove().draw();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            //Like record
            table.on('click', '.like', function() {
                alert('You clicked on Like button');
            });

            $('.card .material-datatables label').addClass('form-group');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: you should add your html/js code to question

Comment: ı added right now

Comment: should add both html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change `dom` to `Bflrtip`

> dom: 'Bflrtip'

[read more about datatables dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)